# SQL query operator minus is not working

Tags: php, mysql, except

```
(SELECT IDOperatore FROM operatore) MINUS 
(SELECT IDOperatore FROM commessaoperatore GROUP BY IDOperatore)
```

This query is no working, even if I try to replace `MINUS` with `EXCEPT`. 
The singular query `SELECT IDOperatore FROM operatore` and `SELECT IDOperatore FROM commessaoperatore GROUP BY IDOperatore` are working, but if I try to put together with `Minus` operator they don't work.

> ERROR:   #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'MINUS (SELECT IDOperatore FROM commessaoperatore GROUP BY IDOperatore)' at line 1

Answer (score 4):

MINUS does not exists in mysql

however for you query you can use NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT IDOperatore FROM operatore o
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM commessaoperatore c 
                 WHERE c.IDOperatore = o.IDOperatore)
```

Comment: the query works but i must GROUP items by IDOperatore, where I must add ->>> GROUP BY IDOperatore

Comment: @vankraster, why you need group them?